# Progress SQL Column cannot be found or is not specified for query

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I'm writing SQL against a Progress 10.2B07 database and am getting the following error "Column 'OUTERINVOICEHEADER.MEMBERID' cannot be found or is not specified for query (13865).

Here is the query:

```
select concat(substring(OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr, 1, 6) + '-', OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq) as MemberID, 
sum(OuterInvoiceHeader.net_weight) as TotalInvoicePounds, 
sum(OuterInvoiceHeader.net_weight / 2000) as TotalTons, 
sum(OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_amt) as InvoiceAmount, 
sum(InvoiceSurcharges.Surcharge) as Surcharges, 
sum(OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_amt - InvoiceSurcharges.Surcharge) as Total,
sum(Returns.qty_received) as PoundsReturned
from AXS.PUB.ivc_header OuterInvoiceHeader

inner join
(select m.invoice_nbr, sum(m.extension) Surcharge  from AXS.PUB.ivc_mchgs m
inner join
AXS.PUB.ivc_header h
on h.invoice_nbr = m.invoice_nbr
group by m.invoice_nbr) InvoiceSurcharges
on OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr = InvoiceSurcharges.invoice_nbr

left outer join
(select concat(substring(ReturnHeader.ship_to_nbr, 1, 6)+'-',InnerInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq) as ReturnMemberID, 
ReturnHeader.invoice_nbr as ReturnInvoiceNum, 
qty_received
from AXS.PUB.return_hdr ReturnHeader
inner join
AXS.PUB.ivc_header InnerInvoiceHeader
on ReturnHeader.invoice_nbr = InnerInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr
inner join AXS.PUB.return_line ReturnLine
on ReturnHeader.claim_nbr = ReturnLine.claim_nbr
where ReturnInvoiceNum = '0001010914'
group by ReturnMemberID, ReturnInvoiceNum, qty_received) Returns
on OuterInvoiceHeader.MemberID = Returns.ReturnMemberID
--on OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr = Returns.ReturnInvoiceNum

where OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr =  '000837' and     OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_date between '06/01/2016' and '06/30/2016' and  OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_status = '5804' and OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_type='5601'
group by MemberID
```

The problem is in the left join; the commented out on clause "on OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr = Returns.ReturnInvoiceNum" will work if uncommented.  The "on OuterInvoiceHeader.MemberID = Returns.ReturnMemberID" clause gives me the error.

What I don't understand is that both of these reference a column in the top SELECT statement, the only difference is that one is a concatenation and the other is not.

I hope that I just can't see the forest for the trees here and the answer is simple, so if anyone has any suggestions or questions I'm all ears.

Comment: you might want to check AXS.PUB.ivc_header to see if you actually have the column MemberID.

Comment: I do have the memberid but that is not the complete id for the company, I have to concatenate the sold_to_cust_seq; each sequence identifies the subsidiary.

Comment: have a look at my answer that should explain the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

I replaced the references to the alias `MemberID` to be the actual concatinated columns `CONCAT(SUBSTRING(OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr, 1, 6)+'-', OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq)`

```
SELECT                     CONCAT(SUBSTRING(OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr, 1, 6)+'-', OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq) AS MemberID
                    , SUM(OuterInvoiceHeader.net_weight) AS TotalInvoicePounds
                    , SUM(OuterInvoiceHeader.net_weight / 2000) AS TotalTons
                    , SUM(OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_amt) AS InvoiceAmount
                    , SUM(InvoiceSurcharges.Surcharge) AS Surcharges
                    , SUM(OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_amt - InvoiceSurcharges.Surcharge) AS Total
                    , SUM(Returns.qty_received) AS PoundsReturned
FROM                       AXS.PUB.ivc_header OuterInvoiceHeader
                      INNER JOIN
                              (SELECT m.invoice_nbr
                                   , SUM(m.extension) Surcharge
                               FROM   AXS.PUB.ivc_mchgs m
                                    INNER JOIN AXS.PUB.ivc_header h ON h.invoice_nbr = m.invoice_nbr
                               GROUP BY m.invoice_nbr) InvoiceSurcharges ON OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr = InvoiceSurcharges.invoice_nbr
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                  (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ReturnHeader.ship_to_nbr, 1, 6)+'-', InnerInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq) AS ReturnMemberID
                                       , ReturnHeader.invoice_nbr AS ReturnInvoiceNum
                                       , qty_received
                                   FROM   AXS.PUB.return_hdr ReturnHeader
                                        INNER JOIN AXS.PUB.ivc_header InnerInvoiceHeader ON ReturnHeader.invoice_nbr = InnerInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr
                                        INNER JOIN AXS.PUB.return_line ReturnLine ON ReturnHeader.claim_nbr = ReturnLine.claim_nbr
                                   WHERE  ReturnInvoiceNum = '0001010914'
                                   GROUP BY ReturnMemberID
                                        , ReturnInvoiceNum
                                        , qty_received) Returns ON CONCAT(SUBSTRING(OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr, 1, 6)+'-', OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq) = Returns.ReturnMemberID
--on OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_nbr = Returns.ReturnInvoiceNum

WHERE OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr = '000837'
     AND OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_date BETWEEN '06/01/2016' AND '06/30/2016'
     AND OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_status = '5804'
     AND OuterInvoiceHeader.invoice_type = '5601'
GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTRING(OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr, 1, 6)+'-', OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq);
```

Basically you need to keep in mind the order which SQL statements are executed:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 1):

That's a computed column alias and thus the error. You should consider using the entire  expression rather like

```
on concat(substring(OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_nbr, 1, 6) + '-', OuterInvoiceHeader.sold_to_cust_seq) = Returns.ReturnMemberID
```

Instead of `on OuterInvoiceHeader.MemberID = Returns.ReturnMemberID`. As well, change any other place where you are using the same alias. You can and should use that alias only in a outer query and not in the same query.

Comment: Both answers are correct, this one came first, that's why I'm marking it as the correct one.  Thanks Rahul and Kamran for the speedy responses, they really helped.

Comment: Hi Colin actually I answered first but that ok :P

Comment: Sorry Kamran, I'm relatively new to SO and still figuring out how it all works.  Now that I look back your answer was posted first, I don't know how I missed it.